# Generic overloads in typescript 2.3 or 2.4 broken

Tags: typescript

The following example broke for me when upgrading from typescript 2.2.

```
interface ILayoutResult {
    id: string;
    data: any;
}
interface ILayout{
    getResult<T extends ILayoutResult | ILayoutResult[] | void>() :T;
}

class test implements ILayout{
    getResult(){
       return {id:"a", data:"aa"} as ILayoutResult ;
    }
}


Types of property 'getResult' are incompatible.
    Type '() => ILayoutResult' is not assignable to type '<T extends void | ILayoutResult | ILayoutResult[]>() => T'.
      Type 'ILayoutResult' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a correct error. The definition for `ILayout` says it's legal to do this:

```
const x: ILayout = ...;
const arr = x.getResult<ILayoutResult[]>();
const j = arr.pop();
```

However, if `x` is an instance of `test`, then this code will fail because you're not actually returning an `ILayoutResult[]`.

The intent was probably to write this, which says that `getResult` might return any of the three types given

```
interface ILayout {
    getResult(): ILayoutResult | ILayoutResult[] | void;
}
```

Comment: I also came to this conclusion. Somehow I adopted this way of adding the generic template such at calling of getResult I could easy tell what type i wanted. But the proper way would be getResult() as ILayoutResult